# Issues with routing with react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a `Home.jsx` component, which has route `"/"`.

- On the right side of it there's some static component, e.g. an image or so.
- On the left side there's a list of users, each of them is a Link (`"/user/:id"`)

When user clicks item of the list, the list itself should **disappear** and the component with specified user details should **appear**, e.g. `"/user/1"`.

When clicking the `back` button or basically on page header it should go back to `"/"` and show the list once again.

**My approach**:
What I have basically done, is:

First of all, the routes (in `App.jsx`):

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/user/:id" component={Home}/>
```

Then, inside `Home.jsx` I was playing with props:

```
if (this.props.match.path === '/') {
   return <UserList />;
} else {
   return <UserDetails userId={userId} />
}
```

**However** and unfortunately - my `Home.jsx` component is being **mounted** with every path change - from `"/"` to `"/user/:id"` and back forwards. So if it re-mounts, every child component is being re-mounted aswell which causes every prop to reload which causes my app to blow...

Would really appreciate any feedback or help how to fix that issue, how to stop it re-mount with every path change. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Check out `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have `Home` be loaded on both paths like you have it. Instead you should be doing `<Route path="/" component={UserList} />` and `<Route path="/user/:id" component={UserDetailst} />` where you currently have that `if` statement. if you show the surrounding function where that `if` statement is I can write an answer

Comment: @FrankerZ that doesn't apply here

Comment: @azium Give me a moment, please, will edit my post

Comment: i wrote an answer anyways, pretty sure its what you need. will update it if need be based on your update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire point of `<Route />` components is to handle what your `if` statement is doing: conditionally render components based on the url.

You want your Home component to render on both `/` and `/user/:id`, not exactly on `/`.

Your App.js file should look like:

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

and inside your Home.js file instead of a function with an if statement, just render `<Route />` components.

You probably have something that looks like

```
<div>
   {this.figureOutWhichComponentToShow()}
   <StaticContent />
</div>
```

change that to:

```
<div>
   <Route exact path="/" component={UserList} />
   <Route path="/user/:id" component={UserDetails} />
   <StaticContent />
</div>
```

and use `this.props.match.params.id` inside your UserDetails component. or you can inline that in the Route

```
<div>
   <Route exact path="/" component={UserList} />
   <Route path="/user/:id" component={props => 
     <UserDetails userId={props.match.params.id} /> 
   }/>
   <StaticContent />
</div>
```

Comment: It works lovely, however the `UserList` does not disappear when clicking on some list item, the `UserDetails` appears nicely and disappears smoothly, but the list stays all the time... Any ideas why?

Comment: did you remember to put `exact`? on the `UserList` route? `<Route exact path="/" component={UserList} />` ?

Comment: Forgot. God bless you, have a great day!